# Noob question, Copying images from old Mac drive to a MyPassport so Windows can see it

Tags: virtualbox, hard-drive, filesystem, mac

I have a VirtualBox set up and Unbuntu installed on the VM.  The host is Windows 10.  Right now I have a few old Mac drives mounted to some USB ports through some dongles (threw out the Macs, boards corrupted)  and they are showing up and I am able to browse them in Unbuntu latest (as of this writing November 1, 2021).
I am trying to transfer some .jpg files from the old drives to my more modern MyPassport drive so my Windows machine can view the images from the old iPhotos library on the old Mac drives.

A couple of questions.

1. Everytime I try to go into some of the folders of the external drive, it prompts me to authenticate each and every time and on every image.  Fairly annoying.  Would really like not to have to do this.  Tried Nautilus, but still ran into permission stuff, so I went back to the user.
2. I am doing a direct "Copy" (right click > Copy), and copying files to the WD MyPassport so my Windows machine to view the files.  The images are just .jpg files.

That said, When I go to the MyPassPort driveI am getting a lock icon, a red 'X' icon AND and 'arrow' icon. Not idea what the X and the arrow icon mean, but figured the lock is Unbuntu wanting me to authenticate to view the file again.  But why the X and the arrow.
[image: Image of file system]

The issue is when I try to open the image file in Unbuntu from the MyPassport drive, it tosses me another fun error:

[image: ErroMessage]

My question is:

1. What is causing the issue between the transfer from the Mac drive to the MyPassport drive?
2. Do I need to copy directly to Unbuntu first then dump it to the MyPassport?  (Since it is a VM I didn't allocate that much space to the partition.  Mostly just to run Unbuntu)
3. Is there a way to transfer the files and get the files to transfer to the MyPassport or am I missing something in this process?

Comment: It looks like you have created symbolic links (since thing similar to shortcuts in Windows) instead of copies.

Comment: How would I go about copying files to the other external hard drive though?  It looks like Unbuntu is creating the link then.  Can I just do a copy of the original file to the new drive without the link?

Comment: I am not sure why Ubuntu is creating links when you right click and select "copy".

Comment: Can you add the full path of the source folder and the full path of the target folder in the question? You do this by navigating to the source folder in Nautilus. Then press CTRL+L. Copy the path from the status bar into the question above in a new line. Format the line as `code` using the {_} icon above the edit window. Repeat for the target folder.

Comment: X and arrow likely mean "broken link". It does not look like Ubuntu created them. I even doubt Ubuntu can write to hfs+, so ...

Comment: I believe in order to read the HFS+ drives from MacOS X you need to install the hfsprogs into Ubuntu then the drive can be remounted.  `sudo apt install hfsprogs`